# how to use fixtures for test and development rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, fixtures, seed

I understand that seed.rb is used to seed the database with data for the application in production.

I want to create some data for use with tests and also for development.

Where should I put the code to create this data?

Thanks

Rails 3.2